# Editing "FamilyType" mapped to a parameter

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am trying to programmatically change the FamilyType that is mapped to a parameter inside a Family (specifically one that creates Weld Annotations).  In this case, the FamilyType(s) in question are only inside the family, so a search for a matching FamilyInstance or FamilySymbol does not apply (nor work, since I tried -- these embedded families do not appear in the browser).  These FamilyType(s) also do not appear using GetSubComponentIds -- the parent weld family reports no sub-components.  A search for "ParameterType" of that parameter returns "FamilyType", but I don't know what value to apply to that parameter if I can't find an ElementId.

```
FilteredElementCollector DetailItems = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
DetailItems.OfClass(typeof(Autodesk.Revit.DB.FamilyInstance));
List<string> Many_Annotations = new List<string>();
foreach (FamilyInstance One_Instance in DetailItems)
{
    ICollection<ElementId> Subbies = One_Instance.GetSubComponentIds();//insists that there are NONE with sub-elements?
    if (Subbies != null)
    {
        foreach (ElementId One_Id in Subbies)//apparently a nested component (parameter controlled) is NOT a sub-component?
        {
            FamilyInstance One_Sub = doc.GetElement(One_Id) as FamilyInstance;
            Many_Annotations = MyNamespace.Class.Unique_Strings(One_Sub.Name, Many_Annotations);
        }
   }
}
```

The code above always results in an empty List.  I understand this may be one of the many items in Revit not yet "exposed".

UPDATE:  I have been able to find the required ElementId of the embedded FamilyTypes assigned to instances of a family, but ONLY if that embedded type has been used in one of the Parameters in all FamilyInstances of the Family in question.  I have been able to use these to enable radio buttons for those particular choices, but I would like to find "possible" parameter values.

Comment: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/id-of-a-nested-element-in-parameter-reports-different-value/td-p/5738935

Answer (score 0):

I find your naming a bit confusing, mixing annotations, detail items and family instances seemingly interchangeably. Have you explored your model using [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup) or the [Revit Python shell](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/11/intimate-revit-database-exploration-with-the-python-shell.html)? You might be able to see directly what is going on, and why no sub components are being returned.

Comment: I called my FilteredElementCollector "DetailItems" only because I had already used one called "Annotations" elsewhere in my code.  I admit it is confusing since the families I am dealing with are annotations.  However, since these annotations are FamilyInstances of a particular category, I don't believe I'm mixing those up.  I mentioned FamilySymbols because one of the things I tried was to collect FamilySymbols and explore their Parameters (to no avail).  As mentioned in my update, I have been able to get "used" ElementId's, but I would like "possible" ones.  I have not used Python before.